# javascript inheritance use previously redefined function

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, reusability

I have come to accept that there is more than one way to do multiple inheritance in javascript. What I don't understand is how to call parent functions. I do it like so

```
function person(name){
 this.name=name;
 this.display=function(){alert(this.name);}
 this.personDisplay=this.display; //pointer to parent function
}
function employee(name,ID){
 this.person=person;
 this.person(name);
 this.ID=ID;
 this.display=function(){this.parentDisplay();alert(this.ID);}
}
```

but I was wondering if there was a correct way to reuse parent functions such as

```
function employee(name,ID){
 this.person=person;
 this.person(name);
 this.ID=ID;
 this.display=function(){parent.display();alert(this.ID);} //ideally what I want
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be multiple inheritance?  For single-inheritance class-based constructors, there are several methods and techniques.  However, you are **strongly** urged to adopt a JavaScript framework that does all of this for you.  I personally recommend the Dojo Toolkit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I called it multiple inheritence. I meant extending functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not multiple inheritance.  Only single inheritance.

In JavaScript, to mimic class-based object-oriented programming, you'll need to use the **prototype**.  JavaScript technically is a *prototypical* language, not an object-oriented one, but you can simulate OO-style classes quite successfully.

Using the prototype is usually "clasical" or "pseudo-classical" style.

Or you can use the "functional" style popularized by Douglas Crockford (just Google it).

Michael Bolin has a [good article](http://www.bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php) discussing these two styles.

Most OO implementations in JavaScript are variants of these two styles.

You are **strongly** urged to adopt a JavaScript library that does all of this for you.  My personal recommendation is the [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org).

Comment: @Stephen: I just went over all the Dojo tutorials, and they did not mention inheritance. Although it does seem to be a lot better than standard javascript. What about, jQuery, do you recomend that as well? Thanx

Comment: jQuery AFAIK does not have a standard class-based mechanism, although there are a few popular plugins.  Dojo is very object-oriented.  Check out the Quick Start Guide http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/index.html and look for dojo.declare.

Comment: @stephen: I have to agree Dojo significantly improves javascript.

Comment: @puk, not just Dojo.  There are a number of popular JavaScript libraries out there.  You should look at them all before making your choice.  That choice is likely going stick with you for yeras.

Comment: @Stephen, @puk: *"...although there are a few popular plugins..."* And soon to be another one; I've been planning to release mine as a jQuery plug-in for some time, and expect to get to it soon. ;-) @puk: [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) also has an inheritance mechanism, although bewarned that its approach to supercalls is very easy to use but very, very expensive at runtime; [details here](http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/msg/1c954d9bbcbb5868). Mind you, 90% of the time, you really don't care 'cause you're not calling these in a tight loop. But when you do...

Comment: @Crowder,@Stephen: Thanx for the advice. Unfortunately, I have lost almost all respect for core javascript after seeing the snazzy Dojo library.

Comment: @puk, don't write off Prototype, jQuery, MooTools, YUI, Ext and Closure Library too quickly.  At your own perils!  Remember, the library you choose should reflect your own programming style and what you need to get done.  Look at them all before you choose!  They are all **great** libraries!

Comment: @TJ Crowder, I think there is a trade-off between runtime performance and ease-of-use.  Somewhat.  Dojo's implementation is dead easy (it is one line `this.inherited`); however it searches a methods chain to find the next implementation.  Still better than the Prototype way.  Closure's way is probably fastest, but quite non-programmer-friendly, and really requires compiler support to simplify.

Comment: @Stephen: Agreed about trade-offs. The big problem with Dojo's is that it uses `arguments.callee`, which is **massively** slow on several implementations (like, slows down method calls by 10x or more) and isn't supported in the new "strict" mode of ECMAScript5. I actually provide the same thing as an adjunct (called `callSuper`), but warn about the costs of using it. @puk: Why would Dojo make you lose respect for JavaScript? Dojo is *made possible* because of the power of the JavaScript language. ;-)

Comment: I have a lot of experience with Python, and I wish javascript was more closely based off of that. I wish all variables were local unless declared global. I don't at all find it intuitive that `x=10;` is global while `var x=10` is local. Python also provides list tools such as `for i in args` or `for i,arg in enumerate(args)` and a whole host of other cool list functionality such as '["arg %d is %s"%(i,arg) for i,arg in enumerate(args)]` to create and return a new list. But at least it's not PHP

Comment: @Stephen: Vis-a-vis `arguments.callee`: http://jsperf.com/callee-vs-name/2 Typically about half the speed, but some (Opera) are much more dramatic. That simple case must be more easily optimised, though, because I did a full-on test case at one point (with inheritance) and it was even larger.

Comment: @stephen,@Crowder: In case anyone is reading this thread, Dojo has one drawback in that it (pseudo) compiles the code, so certain changes have to be made to the script. For example, order is now important when including the scripts, not just for classes, but for global variables too.

Comment: @puk, Dojo does not compile JavaScript code -- in fact, it is impossible to compile JavaScript code and has it run on common browsers.  Do you mean "compress" the code?  The version you server should be the "minified" one since it is smaller and downloads quicker.  Order is **ALWAYS** important when including JavaScript script files, regardless you are using a library or not.  This is one of the differences between JavaScript and Python (substitute many other languages).

Comment: @puk, just a hunch, have you remembered to use `dojo.ready(...)` or `dojo.addOnLoad(...)` to make sure that the library is initialized before using it in your own code?  This is 101 for most libraries and a must if you serve the library from CDN's.

Comment: @stephen, it does seem there is some compiling going on with Dojo. I realize this is not the C compiler, but what I meant is that you no longer have the flexibility you had with pure JS.

Comment: @puk, that is exactly correct.  **JavaScript** requires ordering of scripts, not Dojo.  You can skip Dojo and write raw JavaScript, but still the ordering will be significant.  For example, you'll have to run the script that builds an object before you run the script that uses that object.  dojo.require/provide tries to make sure that any dependent modules are loaded before running anything below that call.  However, make sure you use `dojo.ready()` because if you are loading Dojo off the CDN, dojo.require calls work asynchronously.

Comment: @puk, my advice is: **FORGET EVERYTHING ABOUT PYTHON**.  JavaScript is **NOT** Python.  In fact, it is completely different.  If you think in Python, you'll get confused very very easily.  "Pure" JavaScript has exactly the same ordering requirements for scripts, except you'll then have to code them all by hand instead of relying on calls like dojo.require to do it for you.

Comment: @puk, forgot to answer you main question.  There is **NO** compilation going on in Dojo.  `dojo.require` pulls in a module and executes the script.  It is not compilation.  In fact, there is **NO** compilation for JavaScript.  PERIOD.

Comment: @Stephen, I think we are talking about different things. In JS, if I have a script A.js `function A(){console.log(B());}` and a script B.js `function B(){return 'it puts the lotion on the skin';}`, unless I am mistaken, it doesn't matter what order one includes A.js versus B.js. Conversely if A.js was `console.log(B)` and B.js was `B='Woa Nelly'`, then if we load A.js before B.js it will complain that B is undefined. Sorry if that made zero sense, I am running on no sleep.

Comment: @Stephen, as for the Python reference, I realize the two languages are different, I was referring to the we scripts (modules) are loaded. To me it seems that, as long as scripts only contain functions, and not dangling commands, the code is first copied, then executed. Basically everything becomes global. Maybe a better comparison would have been the Python `exec` call or Lisp Macros.

Comment: @puk, you are correct. As long as your code in both script files don't depend on each other.  In other languages, even if you have class A extending class B, you can include script B before script A and the system will figure it out.  In JavaScript, you'll get an error saying class A is not defined.  That is because, as I have said from the very beginning, **JAVASCRIPT HAS NO CLASSES**!  Any resembemlence of classes is a "hack" from a library to make it **look** like a class, not a **real** one

Comment: JavaScript is not an OOP language.  Therefore it has NO CLASSES.  JavaScript is at heart one very long sequence of statements, one executed after another.  Think of it as BASIC -- one line after another.  That's why ordering is significant.  It is an *imperative* interpreted language, not a class-based or object-based language that is compiled.  What dojo.require/dojo.provide does for you is to automatically manage the dependencies so that ordering of script inclusion is always correct.

Comment: @stephen: I see what the confusion is, my wording was too loose. JS is not object oriented, but there is a workaround solution to this (`function child(){this.parent=parent;this.parent();}`) Dojo provides OO like syntax (`dojo.declare("Child", [Parent]...`). In Dojo child gets automatically executed so parent.js MUST have been loaded when child.js is loaded. In pure JS, either child or parent can be loaded first, as long as a child class is initialized only AFTER parent has been loaded.

Comment: @puk, agreed.  The particular OO implementation provided by Dojo requires base classes to be defined before their children classes.  Usually this is done via dojo.require/dojo.provide.  However, you can definitely program a system in which the classes are defined out-of-order, but only initialized in-order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following your code (you refer to a `parentDisplay` function that isn't defined anywhere; did you meant `personDisplay`?), but if you want to take advantage of JavaScript's prototypical inheritance, you can't use *any* property on `this` to refer to the parent because you'll run into the grand-child problem: It's easy to create a parent/child hierarchy that way, but it fails as soon as you try to create a grandparent/parent/child hierarchy. This is because the object instance is always a child, even when parent code is running, and so if parent code tries to use the same property to refer to *its* parents' code, it ends up referring back to itself and recursing until the stack runs out.

So you use something other than a property on `this`. My solution is to use a property on the function instances themselves and a bit of plumbing. When defining the subclass, you assign the superclass's version of the function to a property on the subclass's version of the function. Then code at all levels can use that property to refer to the parent version of the function.

I outline this in detail in this blog post: ***[Simple, Efficient Supercalls in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html)***. Using the helper created in the article, you can then do this:

```
var Parent = Helper.makeClass(function(){
    function foo() {
        return "P";
    }
    return {foo: foo};
});

var Child = Helper.makeClass(Parent, function(){
    function foo() {
        return foo.$super.call(this) + " < C";
    }
    return {foo: foo};
});

var GrandChild = Helper.makeClass(Child, function(){
    function foo() {
        return foo.$super.call(this) + " < GC";
    }
    return {foo: foo};
});

var gc = new GrandChild();
alert(gc.hierarchy()); // Alerts "P < C < GC"
```

(I don't like to call them classes any more, they're not classes, they're constructor functions. But the article still has the `makeClass` name, so...)

Note the handy scoping functions so you can have utility functions for your "classes" that are completely hidden away from the outside world; and so your instance functions can have proper names, [which is a good thing](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).

Comment: @Crowder: I was worried that I would have to do a lot of plumbing. Darn

Comment: @puk: It's really not a lot of plumbing. The code in that article is fairly verbose for clarity purposes, but even the final result with full comments, support for mixins, and support for after-the-fact hierarchy mods (an edge case), it's only 217 lines; not that much to grok. In distribution terms, [minified](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) it's 2,115 chars; the [Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) in simple mode gets it to 1,242 chars and in advanced mode (you have to do a couple of *minor* edits to make it compatible with adv mode) it's 1,156 chars.

Comment: @puk, that really isn't a lot of plumbing.  @Crowder's implementation is really one of the shortest and simplest I've ever seen!  Comprehensive enough to do *real* work, that is.  However, I won't suggest you do it yourself though.